# Linear Engel Curve

Tags: utility, preferences, demand, wealth

How to prove that if the Engel curves (expenditures as a function of wealth) are linear in wealth, then the indirect utility function has the form $v_{i}(p,a_{i})=\alpha_{i}(p)+\beta(p)a_{i}$ for an agent with utility function $u_{i}$? I think the converse statement is easy by using Roy's Identity, but how about this one? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please define the variables in your notation?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to give the notation. p is the price and a is the wealth. alpha and beta is two coefficients depend on p only.

Answer (score 2):

I think this statement is untrue. Gorman form is a sufficient condition for linear Engle curves, but it is not necessary. Consider the following example:
$$v(p,a_i)=\beta(p)a_i^2$$
Applying Roy's lemma yield demands which are still linear in $a$.

Comment: The reasoning seems reasonable. I would check it. Thanks a lot!